# Git pull --rebase generates two commits ahead

Tags: git, github

**Scenario:**

1. I worked on a local branch `mainline` and I made the commit `CommitA` on this branch and pushed the changes to `origin/mainline`.
2. At the same time, I had another local branch `dev` and I made a commit `CommitB` before pushing the changes from `CommitA` into the remote branch.
3. So 1 happened, all changes were in the remote branch (from local `mainline`) and I wanted to push the changes into the same `origin/mainline` from local `dev` branch.

**What I did:**

4. On branch `dev`, I typed `git pull --rebase origin mainline`, to firstly bring the changes from there.
5. This generated some conflcits, I resolved them then typed `git rebase --continue`.
6. Item 5 generated two commits `CommitA` first then `CommitB` second. This gives me `Your branch is ahead by 2 commits`.

**Question:**

1. In item 6 above, I had two commits, one with the same name `CommitA`, as the one from item 2. (but they have different hashes). Is it safe to `git push origin/mainline` both commits generated in item 6 ??
2. Did I proceed correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on `dev` for which remote is say `origin/dev`. And your local branch `dev` is ahead of remote dev by two commits.
Do a `>git branch -vv`
It will describe your local branches and their remotes.
If you want to push from your local dev branch to `origin/mainline`, you can do that. It should push `commitB` to `origin/mainline`.

I assume you know about `--set-upstream`
The difference in history is because of rebase. I think the documentation should help: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing 
I big quoted text below. Posting it here for the sake of ready reference.

> Now, the snapshot pointed to by C4' is exactly the same as the one
>   that was pointed to by C5 in the merge example. There is no difference
>   in the end product of the integration, but rebasing makes for a
>   cleaner history. If you examine the log of a rebased branch, it looks
>   like a linear history: it appears that all the work happened in
>   series, even when it originally happened in parallel.
>
> Often, you’ll do this to make sure your commits apply cleanly on a
>   remote branch — perhaps in a project to which you’re trying to
>   contribute but that you don’t maintain. In this case, you’d do your
>   work in a branch and then rebase your work onto origin/master when you
>   were ready to submit your patches to the main project. That way, the
>   maintainer doesn’t have to do any integration work — just a
>   fast-forward or a clean apply.
>
> Note that the snapshot pointed to by the final commit you end up with,
>   whether it’s the last of the rebased commits for a rebase or the final
>   merge commit after a merge, is the same snapshot – it’s only the
>   history that is different. Rebasing replays changes from one line of
>   work onto another in the order they were introduced, whereas merging
>   takes the endpoints and merges them together.

Comment: Yes I know, but I have only remote `origin/mainline`. And I get `two commits ahead of origin/mainline`. My question is `CommitA` generated in `Item 5` will replace the `CommitA` generated in 1 ??

Comment: I think after you did a --rebase it should have shown only one commit ahead. So I guess your local dev branch pointing to some other remote branch. But, git is smart. :) It compares contents. So, they are both same commits really. It keeps tracks as well (and probably that's reason why two different hashes). I did not try this. But if after you push to origin/mainline, you visit the commit history, it would should only two commits- not three. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8 Anyone, if you read the comment, please correct if I am wrong.. I don't have my workstation at hand

Comment: That's what I'm curious about.

Comment: did you try > git branch --vv

Comment: Yes, both track `origin/mainline`

Comment: It seems logical after I read the documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Note that the snapshot pointed to by the final commit you end up with, whether it’s the last of the rebased commits for a rebase or the final merge commit after a merge, is the same snapshot – it’s only the history that is different. Rebasing replays changes from one line of work onto another in the order they were introduced, whereas merging takes the endpoints and merges them together.

Comment: So everything should be fine, as expected.